# Why do I keep getting this error when creating a trigger?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, ddl

I am creating a trigger that checks if the Majorcode column is null BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE and if it is it enters the default value "100"

My code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MUmajorcode_changes
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON M_Students
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF NEW.Majorcode = null THEN
    SET NEW.Majorcode = '100';
 END IF;
```

I get the following message after running it
Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

Then when I actually insert a new value with blank major code.

I receive the following message/error:

ERROR at line 1:

```
ORA-04098: trigger 'SCOTT.MUMAJORCODE_CHANGES' is invalid and failed re-validation.
```

This is how I setup the table initially:

```
CREATE TABLE M_Students 
(
 ID           CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
 FName        VARCHAR2(25), 
 LName        VARCHAR2(25), 
 Status       VARCHAR2(25), 
 Majorcode    CHAR(3) REFERENCES Departments(DeptCode), 
 GPA          NUMBER (4,2), 
 AdmittedDate DATE
);
```

Cannot figure out where I am going wrong?

Comment: Several errorsTwo things: your better test 'is null' and not '= null'. And you need an END to end the trigger, and the NEW should be preceded by ':', and remove the SET. To find the errors raised when creating a trigger in sqlplus, do 'show err' after creating it.

Comment: _Cannot figure out where I am going wrong?_ You are not using correct PL/SQL syntax. Oracle documentation is your friend. Search for "PL/SQL Language Reference" for the version of Oracle database that you are using.

Comment: Did you try using Oracle DEFAULT ON NULL you may not need the trigger,  ALTER TABLE M_Students MODIFY Majorcode  DEFAULT ON NULL '100';

Comment: @Baloo - If any of the answers resolved your issue then please accept that answer. This helps future questioners with similar questions as to what has worked previously. If nothing has helped hen update the question with what is still unresolved. Just do not leave a successfully answered question unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

When you get the message "created with compilation errors" it means your script is invalid, it has compile time errors. If your IDE does not show them you to you then if you are using sqlplus then run "show errors" if you are using an IDE run the query "select * from user_errors" (and get a new IDE). Either will show the errors in the script, they must be corrected; your script *will not run until they are*.  
The suggestions of setting a DEFAULT value in the table definition has merit but will fail on a couple conditions. When Inserting the default will be taken when the column name is not mentioned in column list. (Note Omitting the column list is implicitly mentioning all columns so the default would not be set.) Nor would it handle update condition.  
Your trigger itself can be reduced to a single statement with the [coalesce](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/COALESCE.html#GUID-3F9007A7-C0CA-4707-9CBA-1DBF2CDE0C87) function:

```
create or replace trigger mumajorcode_changes  
    before insert or update of mumajorcode 
    on m_students
   for each row
begin
    :new.majorcode := coalesce(:new.majorcode, '100');       
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MUmajorcode_changes /* better use REPLACE to avoid dropping the trigger */
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON M_Students
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF :new.Majorcode IS NULL         /* :new, with the colon (:) */
   THEN
      :new.Majorcode := '100';       /* :new, and no SET */
   END IF;
END;                                 /* a missing END */
```

Also, never check null values with `=`, but always use `is [not] null`.

Comment: Just to explain to the OP about about 'is null'.  nulls, _by definition_ are "undefined" value. Testing for nulls with a standard relational operator will always return "not true".  Thus, 'WHERE MYVAR > NULL', or WHERE MYVAR < NULL  or WHERE MYVAR = NULL or WHERE MYVAR != NULL will _all_ evaluate to 'not true'.

Answer (score 0):

There are some obvious syntax errors such as wrong assignment, missing or superfluous keywords, but you don't need to create a database trigger to handle this operation. Just modify the related columns property by

```
ALTER TABLE M_Students 
MODIFY Majorcode DEFAULT '100' NOT NULL
```

Through this property, `Majorcode` column is already populated by the value `'100'` during the insertion automatically, and updating that column to `NULL` won't be possible because of the `NOT NULL` constraint.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0256f5a157ed0ea079a6ae9645cc62a9)</kbd>